# variable name of src parameter of image in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, parameters

How can I define src parameter in React jsx imgage tag? I map an array and I need define src parameter depends on index of array.

```
import leaf1 from "../../assets/menu-clip/leafes/leaf1.png";
import leaf2 from "../../assets/menu-clip/leafes/leaf2.png";
import leaf3 from "../../assets/menu-clip/leafes/leaf3.png";
import leaf4 from "../../assets/menu-clip/leafes/leaf4.png";
import leaf5 from "../../assets/menu-clip/leafes/leaf5.png";


export default function Menu(props) {


    const menuList = props.menu.menuList;

    return (
        <div className={styles.menuContainer}>
            <ul className={styles.list}>
                {menuList.map( (m,i) => (
                    <li className={styles.menuLi}
                        key={i}>
                        {m.name}
                        <img src={  **leaf + (i+1)** }      // ???????
                             alt="menu lístok"
                             width="50"/>
                    </li>
                )
                )}
            </ul>

        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: How are you building your app, CRA? Whatever it is, you need to handling support for importing images (I think CRA supports it by default). Then once you do, you can just pass it straight to the `src` parameter, e.g. `src={leaf1}`

Comment: Yes CRA, but I need display image depends on name leaf1, leaf2, leaf3... And I need something like `src={ leaf + (i+1) }`

Comment: First of all wrap the src in {}. `<img src={require('./logo.jpeg')} />`

Comment: Oh woops, my mistake misread the question. You can't reference variable/function names dynamically in that kind of way, so you're best off putting the imported images into an array, and using the index from the menuList map as the index for the leaf image array. Give Adithya's answer a try, that might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import leaf1 from "../../assets/menu-clip/leafes/leaf1.png";
import leaf2 from "../../assets/menu-clip/leafes/leaf2.png";
import leaf3 from "../../assets/menu-clip/leafes/leaf3.png";
import leaf4 from "../../assets/menu-clip/leafes/leaf4.png";
import leaf5 from "../../assets/menu-clip/leafes/leaf5.png";


export default function Menu(props) {
  const menuList = props.menu.menuList;
  const leafArray = [leaf1, leaf2, leaf3, leaf4, leaf5];
  return (
    <div className={styles.menuContainer}>
      <ul className={styles.list}>
        {
          menuList.map( (m,i) => (
            <li className={styles.menuLi}
              key={i}>
              {m.name}
              <img src={ leafArray[i] }
                alt="menu lístok"
                width="50"/>
            </li>
          ))
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could store it in a array and reference that

like

```
const leafs = [leaf1,leaf2,...]
//then 
src={leafs[i+1]}
```

Comment: @mirov great! If this answers your question, please upvote it and mark as the correct answer (the tick button below the downvote button) so that the question is officially closed :)